# Is there a term for how English replaces the preposition "of" by putting the word that comes after "of" before the word that comes before "of"?

Tags: syntax, english, grammar

EG,

Apple Juice --> (The) Juice of Apple(s)

Gold Castle --> (The) Castle of Gold

Liver Disease --> Disease of (the) Liver

Et Al.

Comment: They're not "replacements", they're just alternative ways of constructing phrases. If anything, the "of" phrases are the replacements, as they are far more unusual phrases and would be marked in normal conversation.

Comment: The process is known is compounding. It is a very productive mechanism in many languages. Compounds are viewed as single words insofar as the have one main word accent, although they are often written as two or more words.

Answer (score 2):

You could see the two first side of the arrow as an example of noun-noun compounding. While there is a space separating the two words, the stress pattern of these phrases behaves more like a single unit.

Comment: They're specifically genitive tatpurusha compounds, though that term is not as common as it was (outside of Sanskrit grammar itself).

Comment: “Gold castle” is stressed like adjective-noun for me.

Comment: @ewawe: I agree. _Gold castle_ isn't a compound. It could be, (like _goldfinch_, _goldsmith_) but it isn't, and doesn't have the stress pattern of a compound. Contrast _black bird_ with _blackbird_.